# Search all keys with a prefix in map of C++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm using map to store data. The map has really big data. I want to find keys that has a prefix, the limit for number of result items is 50. I want to use fastest way for search, not iterate through whole map and check, since map is a structured key-value container already.

For example, if I have some pairs:

```
<"foo123", value>

<"foo234", value>

<"bar12", value>

<"foo456", value> 

<"bar200", value>
```

if I search for "foo", it will suggest for me

```
foo123, foo234, foo456.
```

Comment: You may use [`std::find_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and provide your own function to check for the prefix.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ That's linear time, and totally unnecessary in this case.

Comment: I researched the question you provided above before asking. I see lower_bound return the first iterator of found key. Can you instruct me how to find the next one. Thanks so much!

Comment: After you find the iterator, you can simply increment it until it no longer matches the prefix or 50 passes. I suggest you close this question, however. In the future, if there's a question strongly resembling your own, perhaps you should reference it, and explain what is the delta between it and the problem you're having.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two approaches that come to mind:

- The first is a special container called [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), for which there is no equivalent in the C++ standard library, but you should be able to locate working versions easily.
- The second approach simply uses the fact that in a `std::map`, the key `"foo"` sorts before `"foo123"`. Using the `upper_bound` or `lower_bound` functions to find a starting range quickly and from there on use a linear search.